# How to use Emacs vc-create-tag with RCS?

Tags: version-control, emacs, tags, snapshot, rcs

I am trying to create a tag (symbolic name) for RCS snapshot. It should be possible with RCS although branches are not supported. I have Ubuntu 10.10 and Emacs 23.1.1. Is some elisp version corrupted, or why does C-x v s behave this way?

BR, Risto

```
Making tag...
```

apply: Wrong number of arguments: #[(backend dir name branchp) "

Answer (score 0):

Quick elisp hack into .emacs:

```
;; Fix broken vc-rcs-create-tag, missing arg from C-x v s
(require 'vc-rcs)
(setq original-vc-rcs-create-tag (symbol-function (function
                                                   vc-rcs-create-tag)))
(defun vc-rcs-create-tag (&rest args)
  (apply original-vc-rcs-create-tag 'RCS args))
```